# PhpStorm + Docker + Composer

Tags: docker, composer-php, phpstorm

Currently working on a project that uses `docker-compose` to create a multi-container application. The majority of the app code lives on my machine but during `docker-compose up` both `composer install` and `npm install` are fired on the docker instance, not on my local machine. Making changes to the source on my local machine is instantly reflected on the Docker, as expected but PhpStorm doesn't see the contents of the `vendor` folder. The `vendor` folder is being exposed as a Volume in the docker-compose file.

Is there a way to tell PhpStorm about the contents of `vendor` on the Docker machine? Currently PhpStorm cannot find any of the `vendor` declarations and I can't use intellisence.

Answer (score 0):

In docker project you have to run you app or api inside a docker container, it's not necessary run it locally, surely you have something like this

```
volumes:
 - .:/usr/src
 - /usr/scr/vendor
```

In this way vendor is "read only".
You should put some code to help you better.

Comment: The app is being run inside a docker container, and yes, there is a volume for the vendor folder as well as the src folder however they are both marked rw, not just read only

Answer (score 0):

I think the `vendor` folder has to be inside your PHPStorm project, too,  otherwise PHPStorm will not be able to inspect it.
So if your PHPStorm project has the following folders:

```
public
src
tests
vendor
```

You could map those into the container like this:

```
    volumes:
      - ./public:/var/www/project/public
      - ./src:/var/www/project/src
      - ./vendor:/var/www/project/vendor
```

At least that's how I did it in recent projects, and both PHPStorm and the container were able to find stuff in vendor folder.
Even if `composer install` is run inside the container, it will put all dependencies into the vendor folder that PHPStorm can access, too.

Comment: docker-compose.yml already has the following volumes defined `- vendordir:/var/www/path/to/root/vendor:rw`

Comment: And is this `vendordir` named `vendor` and inside the PHPStorm project?